# Time data "......." does not match format "%Y-%m-%d / %H:%M:%S.%f"

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

```
df2['Fecha y Hora'] = df2['Fecha'] + '/' + df2['Hora']
df2['Fecha y hora'] = df2['Fecha y Hora'].apply(lambda _: datetime.strptime(_,"%Y-%m-%d / %H:%M:%S.%f"))
df2
```

> Buenas noches, vengo a pedir a ayuda ya que he intentado correr esta parte de un programa que estoy realizando y simplemente no convierte a tipo fecha y hora, como se muestra en el código. De una tabla, junte 2 columnas: "Fecha" y "Hora", par hacerlas solo una (como se muestra en la primera línea de código), sin embargo, al momento de querer convetirla de "object" a "datetime64", me sale error.

Comment: Añade algún dato de ejemplo de las fechas que componen tu variable `df2`. Si no, es imposible ayudarte.

Comment: Así, sin ver ningún ejemplo: al juntar fecha y hora lo haces separando con la cadena `'/'`, pero en el _parseo_ estás considerando una separación `' / '`, con espacios delante y detrás. ¿No será esos espacios el problema?

Answer (score 0):

Suponiendo que el codigo que pones se ejecuta seguido, al intentar ejecutarlo em sale un error en la funcion apply, ya que df2['Fecha y Hora'] es un string, y por tanto no puedes usar apply

```
df2 = {
    'Fecha': '2023-08-10',
    'Hora': '08:08'
}
df2['Fecha y Hora'] = df2['Fecha'] + '/' + df2['Hora']
df2['Fecha y hora'] = df2['Fecha y Hora'].apply(lambda _: datetime.strptime(_,"%Y-%m-%d / %H:%M:%S.%f"))
print(df2) # AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'apply'
```

Mi sugerencia es, que si estas usando una tabla como mencionas, uses directamente objetos datetime

```
from datetime import datetime

df2 = {
    'Fecha': '2023-08-10',
    'Hora': '08:08'
}

fecha = datetime.strptime(df2['Fecha'], '%Y-%m-%d')
print(fecha) # 2023-08-10 00:00:00

_hora, _minutos = df2['Hora'].split(':')

fecha = fecha.replace(hour=int(_hora), minute=int(_minutos))

print(fecha) # 2023-08-10 08:08:00
```